# Unable to set xdebug.idekey in Apache conf

Tags: xdebug, sublimetext2

While trying to configure my Sublime Text 2 IDE to work with Xdebug, I noticed in phpinfo() that the xdebug.idekey value was set to "root".  I've tried many ways to change this and searched everywhere.  According to the Xdebug docs, if not set implicitly, it will first to the DBGP_IDEKEY, USER and USERNAME environment variables (in that order) and use whichever is first found with a value set.  In my development environment, USER was the winner with a value of "ROOT".  Still, when I set DBGP_IDEKEY in my vhost conf file (and verified it), xdebug.idekey is still "root".

Where else can this be coming from or how can I get around it.  ST2 is looking for the idekey to be sublime.xdebug, so I have to get this set somehow to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way of using this is using one of the browser extensions to enable/disable Xdebug: http://xdebug.org/docs/remote#browser-extensions -- all of those will allow you to set an idekey. Alternatively, you can specify as GET parameter: XDEBUG_SESSION_START=submlime.xdebug

As a note though, Sublime Text is *incorrect* to have to require a specific IDEKEY. They are meant so that different users can debug on the same machine. A good IDE should not care which IDEKEY is set for this reason. See also: http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php#connection-initialization